# Directional derivatives at certain points

Tags: calculus

> Consider the function $f(x,y,z) = |x+y+z|$. If ${\bf a} =
>  (a_1,a_2,a_3)$ satisfies $a_1+a_2+a_3=0$ find those directions ${\bf
>  v}$ in which the derivative at ${\bf a}$ exists.

### Attempt

Note that $f(a_1,a_2,a_3) = 0$. So, if ${\bf v } = (v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is any vector we have

$$ D_{\bf v} f( {\bf a} ) = \lim_{s \to 0} \frac{ f( a_i + s v_i ) - f(a_i ) }{s} $$

but $f(a_i) = 0$ and $f(a_i+sv_i) = |a_1 + sv_1 + a_2 + sv_2 + a_3 + sv_3| = s |v_1+v_2+v_3|$

So,

$$ D_{\bf v} f( {\bf a}) = \lim_{s \to 0} \frac{  s |v_1+v_2+v_3| }{s} = |v_1+v_2+v_3| = f ({\bf v})$$

but inst this hold for any $v$ and so the derivative of $f$ at ${\bf a}$ exists at all directions. Is this correct?

Comment: This is "close" to being correct but there is an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directional derivative exists if limits as $s \to 0+$ from the right and as $s \to 0-$ from the left both exist and are equal.

You overlooked the fact that $|s v_1 + sv_2 + sv_3| = |s||v_1 + v_2 +v_3| \neq s|v_1 + v_2 +v_3|$ if $s < 0$.

Thus,

$$\frac{f(\mathbf{a}+ s\mathbf{v}) - f(\mathbf{a})}{s} = \frac{|s|}{s}|v_1+v_2 + v_3| = \text{sgn}(s)|v_1 + v_2 + v_3|,$$

and left- and right-limits are unequal (due to opposite sign)  unless $|v_1 + v_2 +v_3| = 0$

Comment: Thanks so much. So this means that the derivative exist only on the direction of vector 

$$ (x,y,z) = (-1,1,0) \alpha + (-1,0,1) \beta $$

where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @JimmySabater: You're welcome and you are correct -- the two-dimensional subspace of vectors with components that sum to 0.